# Get rid of transparency box outside of Artboards?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, artboard

I just started using artboards in Photoshop, and noticed that a transparency box generates around and between the artboards as I create and move them.

I want this background to disappear so I only see the black background behind the artboards. I scanned through preferences and various option Windows trying to find the answer, but couldn't.

So how can I make this background transparency box go away?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What version of Photoshop are you using?  I can't replicate the problem in CC 2018.

Comment: Thank you @BillyKerr for commenting! I'm using Photoshop CC 2018 as well, and I literally just updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Preferences > Performance > Graphics Processor Settings > Advanced Settings try changing the Drawing Mode to Normal or Basic.